Problems while transmitting the data using UDP
I wrote a program for client and server like, it'll send a command to server where it executes the times mentioned by user, and sends the content by 64 bytes per transmission until all data is sent to client and printed. The problem is it didn't work as I expected, and I checked for errors and I couldn't solve the problem. Please help me, and i'll attach both client and server programs.
Client:
#include <sys/socket.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <errno.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <sys/socket.h>
#include <netinet/in.h>
#include <arpa/inet.h>

typedef struct sockaddr_in sock;
typedef struct sockaddr sck;

int main()
{
    char cmd[10],rcv[65];
    int tm,end,ack = 1;

    printf("Enter any standard LS command: ");
    scanf("%s",cmd);
    printf("Enter no.of times to be executed: ");
    scanf("%d",&tm);

    int sockfd = socket(AF_INET,SOCK_DGRAM,0);
    sock addr;
    int len = sizeof(addr);

    addr.sin_family = AF_INET;
    addr.sin_port = htons(5000);
    addr.sin_addr.s_addr = inet_addr("127.0.0.1");

    sendto(sockfd,cmd,sizeof(cmd),0,(sck *)&addr,len);
    sendto(sockfd,&tm,sizeof(int),0,(sck *)&addr,len);

    while(end)
    {
        int sz = recvfrom(sockfd,rcv,sizeof(rcv),0,(sck *)&addr,&len);
        printf("%s\n",rcv);

        if(sz == 64)
            sendto(sockfd,&ack,sizeof(int),0,(sck *)&addr,len);
        else
        {
            ack = 0;
            sendto(sockfd,&ack,sizeof(int),0,(sck *)&addr,len);
        }

        recvfrom(sockfd,&end,sizeof(int),0,(sck *)&addr,&len);
    }

    close(sockfd);
}

Server:
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <sys/wait.h>
#include <sys/socket.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <fcntl.h>
#include <errno.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <sys/socket.h>
#include <netinet/in.h>
#include <arpa/inet.h>

typedef struct sockaddr_in sock;
typedef struct sockaddr sck;

int main()
{
    char cmd[10],snd[65],ch;
    int tm,cn = 0,end = 1, ack;

    int sockfd = socket(AF_INET,SOCK_DGRAM,0);
    sock addr;
    int len = sizeof(addr);

    addr.sin_family = AF_INET;
    addr.sin_port = htons(5000);
    addr.sin_addr.s_addr = inet_addr("127.0.0.1");

    bind(sockfd,(sck *)&addr,sizeof(addr));

    recvfrom(sockfd,cmd,sizeof(cmd),0,(sck *)&addr,&len);
    recvfrom(sockfd,&tm,sizeof(int),0,(sck *)&addr,&len);

    int fd = open("op.txt",O_CREAT | O_WRONLY | O_TRUNC,0644);
    int bc = dup(1);
    dup2(fd,1);

    for(int i = 1;i <= tm;i++)
        system(cmd);

    close(fd);
    dup2(bc,1);

    fd = open("op.txt",O_RDONLY);

    while(read(fd,&ch,1))
    {
        if(cn < 64)
            snd[cn] = ch;
        else
        {
            snd[cn] = '\0';
            sendto(sockfd,snd,sizeof(snd),0,(sck *)&addr,len);
            recvfrom(sockfd,&ack,sizeof(ack),0,(sck *)&addr,&len);
            if(!ack)
            {
                end = 0;
                sendto(sockfd,&end,sizeof(int),0,(sck *)&addr,len);
                break;
            }
            else
                sendto(sockfd,&end,sizeof(int),0,(sck *)&addr,len);
            cn = 0;
        }
        cn++;
    }

    close(fd);
    close(sockfd);
}


before downvoting please mention the reason

NMDV, yet better 1) to provide sample input, output seen and expected output.  2) check the return value of I/O functions (and others too).  "didn't work as I expected" is not an informative description.

one problem, end is uninitialized in the client code, so you have no idea what will happen when it reaches while(end) the first time

"The problem is it didn't work as I expected" This is not a useful description of your issue. What did happen when you tried it? What did you expect to happen instead? What data was used in the test? To find out where you have a problem, you must identify the step that fails: Have you verified (using Wireshark, use a second PC's IP address for server instead, to make debugging easier than using 127.0.0.1) that the data is transmitted to the server correctly? Have you checked whether the response data is transmitted correctly?

BTW: You send multiple packets to transmit your response. UDP is a connectionless protocol. You have no indication whether all packets were transmitted successfully, and there is also no warantee that the packets are received in the same sequence as you send them.

did not work as expected - downvote.

Remember that UDP is a fire-and-forget protocol that does not care that the other end did not receive what was sent. In fact, you will lose packets on the network, so to make UDP reliable, you need to put an application-layer protocol on top of it.

Aside: Try to avoid sizeof(type), prefer sizeof variable. E.g. sizeof tm instead of sizeof(int)

Are 0 packets arriving?

I cautiously assume the original intention of your question is like

Client

Client sends some system commands, such as ls -al . and the repetition counts(how many times does the server execute the given command from the client), for example, 3.
After the server's execution of the command repeatedly, displays the output on the client's display as well.


Server

Receives the command and repetition count from the client. (for example, ls -al ., 3)
Executes the command the specified number of times.
Stores the combined output into op.txt (at least your code seems to be working with this file).
Sends the contents of op.txt back to the client again.



Based on this assumption, I rewrote the program again.
// server.c
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <errno.h>
#include <arpa/inet.h>
#include <sys/socket.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <fcntl.h>

#define SERVER_PORT 5000
#define BUFFER_SIZE 1024
#define OUTPUT_FILE "op.txt"
#define END_MESSAGE "END"

// Function to send data to the client
void send_data(int sockfd, struct sockaddr_in *client_addr, socklen_t addr_len, const char *data, size_t data_len) {
    ssize_t sent_bytes = sendto(sockfd, data, data_len, 0, (struct sockaddr *)client_addr, addr_len);
    if (sent_bytes == -1) {
        perror("sendto failed");
    }
}

int main() {
    int sockfd;
    struct sockaddr_in server_addr, client_addr;
    socklen_t addr_len = sizeof(client_addr);
    char buffer[BUFFER_SIZE];
    char command[256];
    int repetition;

    // Create UDP socket
    sockfd = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_DGRAM, 0);
    if (sockfd == -1) {
        perror("socket creation failed");
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }

    // Bind the socket to server address
    memset(&server_addr, 0, sizeof(server_addr));
    server_addr.sin_family = AF_INET;
    server_addr.sin_port = htons(SERVER_PORT);
    server_addr.sin_addr.s_addr = INADDR_ANY; // Listen on all interfaces

    if (bind(sockfd, (struct sockaddr *)&server_addr, sizeof(server_addr)) == -1) {
        perror("bind failed");
        close(sockfd);
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }

    printf("Server is up and listening on port %d...\n", SERVER_PORT);

    // Receive command from client
    ssize_t bytes_received = recvfrom(sockfd, buffer, BUFFER_SIZE - 1, 0, (struct sockaddr *)&client_addr, &addr_len);
    if (bytes_received == -1) {
        perror("recvfrom failed for command");
        close(sockfd);
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }
    buffer[bytes_received] = '\0';
    strncpy(command, buffer, sizeof(command) - 1);
    command[sizeof(command) - 1] = '\0'; // Ensure null-termination
    printf("Received command: %s\n", command);

    // Receive repetition count from client
    bytes_received = recvfrom(sockfd, &repetition, sizeof(repetition), 0, (struct sockaddr *)&client_addr, &addr_len);
    if (bytes_received == -1) {
        perror("recvfrom failed for repetition count");
        close(sockfd);
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }
    printf("Repetition count: %d\n", repetition);

    // Execute the command the specified number of times and capture the output
    FILE *fp = fopen(OUTPUT_FILE, "w");
    if (fp == NULL) {
        perror("Failed to open output file");
        close(sockfd);
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }

    // Redirect stdout to the file
    int stdout_copy = dup(STDOUT_FILENO);
    if (stdout_copy == -1) {
        perror("dup failed");
        fclose(fp);
        close(sockfd);
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }

    if (dup2(fileno(fp), STDOUT_FILENO) == -1) {
        perror("dup2 failed");
        fclose(fp);
        close(sockfd);
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }

    // Execute the command multiple times
    for (int i = 0; i < repetition; i++) {
        printf("Execution %d:\n", i + 1);
        if (system(command) == -1) {
            fprintf(stderr, "Failed to execute command: %s\n", command);
        }
        printf("\n"); // Add spacing between executions
    }

    // Restore stdout
    if (dup2(stdout_copy, STDOUT_FILENO) == -1) {
        perror("dup2 restore failed");
    }
    close(stdout_copy);
    fclose(fp);

    // Open the output file for reading
    fp = fopen(OUTPUT_FILE, "r");
    if (fp == NULL) {
        perror("Failed to open output file for reading");
        close(sockfd);
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }

    printf("Sending output to client...\n");

    // Send the file content in chunks
    while (fgets(buffer, sizeof(buffer), fp) != NULL) {
        send_data(sockfd, &client_addr, addr_len, buffer, strlen(buffer));
        usleep(10000);
    }

    // Send the END message to indicate completion
    send_data(sockfd, &client_addr, addr_len, END_MESSAGE, strlen(END_MESSAGE) + 1);

    printf("Output sent successfully.\n");

    fclose(fp);
    close(sockfd);
    return 0;
}

// client.c
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <arpa/inet.h>
#include <sys/socket.h>

#define SERVER_PORT 5000
#define SERVER_IP "127.0.0.1"
#define BUFFER_SIZE 1024
#define END_MESSAGE "END"

// Function to send data to the server
void send_data(int sockfd, struct sockaddr_in *server_addr, socklen_t addr_len, const char *data, size_t data_len) {
    ssize_t sent_bytes = sendto(sockfd, data, data_len, 0, (struct sockaddr *)server_addr, addr_len);
    if (sent_bytes == -1) {
        perror("sendto failed");
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }
}

// Function to receive data from the server
ssize_t receive_data(int sockfd, char *buffer, size_t buffer_size, struct sockaddr_in *server_addr, socklen_t *addr_len) {
    ssize_t received_bytes = recvfrom(sockfd, buffer, buffer_size - 1, 0, (struct sockaddr *)server_addr, addr_len);
    if (received_bytes == -1) {
        perror("recvfrom failed");
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }
    buffer[received_bytes] = '\0'; // Null-terminate the received data
    return received_bytes;
}

int main() {
    char command[256];
    int repetition;
    char buffer[BUFFER_SIZE];
    struct sockaddr_in server_addr;
    socklen_t addr_len = sizeof(server_addr);

    // Get user input
    printf("Enter the command to execute (e.g., ls -al .): ");
    fgets(command, sizeof(command), stdin);
    command[strcspn(command, "\n")] = '\0'; // Remove newline character

    printf("Enter the number of times to execute the command: ");
    if (scanf("%d", &repetition) != 1 || repetition < 1) {
        fprintf(stderr, "Invalid repetition count.\n");
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }

    // Create UDP socket
    int sockfd = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_DGRAM, 0);
    if (sockfd == -1) {
        perror("socket creation failed");
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }

    // Configure server address
    memset(&server_addr, 0, sizeof(server_addr));
    server_addr.sin_family = AF_INET;
    server_addr.sin_port = htons(SERVER_PORT);
    if(inet_aton(SERVER_IP, &server_addr.sin_addr) == 0){
        fprintf(stderr, "Invalid server IP address.\n");
        close(sockfd);
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }

    // Send command length and command
    send_data(sockfd, &server_addr, addr_len, command, strlen(command) + 1);

    // Send repetition count
    send_data(sockfd, &server_addr, addr_len, (char *)&repetition, sizeof(repetition));

    printf("\n--- Receiving Output ---\n");

    // Receive data until "END" message is received
    while (1) {
        ssize_t bytes_received = receive_data(sockfd, buffer, BUFFER_SIZE, &server_addr, &addr_len);
        if (strcmp(buffer, END_MESSAGE) == 0) {
            printf("\n--- End of Output ---\n");
            break;
        }
        printf("%s", buffer);
    }

    close(sockfd);
    return 0;
}

An example execution would be like


I hope this is what you wanted at that moment...
